# Exporting cropped PNG with Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I'm using the tool "Export As" with Photoshop CC to get an icon from a .psd file and save it into a .png file. It worked well so far with other things but this time the icon comes cropped.

This is how it looks like when I zoom in and select it in the .psd file:

[image]

Then I select "Export As..." and it comes cropped:

[image]

What I tried is to change the canvas size, but it only adds blank space below and to the right side.

How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I just found the way. I converted it to a Smart Object and now it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Photoshop solves a lot of exporting issues. And if you have Photoshop CC you could also try to use Adobe Generator.